# when I clicked notification I want to continue app , not start an intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have a `Service` which listening the socket and when data came creating a notification. When users click the notification starting `MainActivity`, but I don't want to start an intent I just want to open app and continue. Because I am showing a map in `MainActivity` and when I started `MainActivity` with an intent it triggers `OnMapReady` function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must look for `android:launchMode` tag. Please refer this page : [activity-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

For instance in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.YasinActivity"
    android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="blabla"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: This is what ı am looking for . It worked ! Really big thank you fast answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding this flag into your PendingIntent **PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT**

e.g:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, YourActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

It opens your application without reloading if app is having background and when your app is destroyed it reloads the app.